# android google maps moving the camera to different locations with animation

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, camera

Hi I am trying to change the camera in different locations with an animation. What happens is that when the map opens it zooms to a location then it stops for 6 secs and then it moves to another location with a camera animation. My question is that when this is finished how can I create a 3rd location and then move the camera from the 2nd location to the 3rd? Any idea guys ? Thanks. Here is my code.

```
   public class THEMAP extends Activity {

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LatLng loc1 = new LatLng(41.889, -87.622);
    LatLng loc2 = new LatLng(45.889, -87.622);
    LatLng loc3 = new LatLng(49.889, -87.622);



    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc1, 10));

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 6000, null);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green))
            .position(loc2)
            .flat(true)
            .rotation(245));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green))
    .position(loc1)
    .flat(true)
    .rotation(245));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green))
    .position(loc3)
    .flat(true)
    .rotation(245));


    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(mapCenter2)     
    .zoom(8)                   
    .bearing(90)                
    .tilt(30)                   
    .build();                   



  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition ),
    8000, null);

   }

  }
```

The problem is that if i add another location+marker and try to do the above code, the map animates only the 3rd location ignoring the animation of the 2nd location. Any advice guys ?Please help.

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition2 = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(loc3)     
    .zoom(8)                  
    .bearing(90)               
    .tilt(30)                   
    .build();                   



   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition2 ),
    8000, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer: http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3

It seems you need to implement the second animation in the onFinish() callback of the second animation.